# Is SonarQube able to analyze react/jsx/es6 code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sonarqube, jsx

Is there a plugin for SonarQube that can analyze react/jsx/es6 code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is planned that the SonarQube JavaScript plugin supports JSX files. By supporting, this means being able to correctly parse JSX files in the first place.

You can watch and vote for [SONARJS-521](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-521).

Comment: Any update on this functionality? Is it live? Could you please share the doc link.